# supress error on dead code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

My eclipse is configured to add error on dead code.
However, some auto-generated java files are having this error.
when it was configured as warning I could add to class definition `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` and the warning was removed.
Is there a similar option when this is an error?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately (for you), unreachable code is *required* by the JLS to be a compilation error; see [JLS 14.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21).  Since the Eclipse Java compiler aims to be JLS compliant, it cannot suppress the error.

You need to fix the generator (or its inputs) so that it doesn't generate invalid Java code.

Comment: Basically what I am asking is different. I *can* suppress it for specific class if it is defined as warning. Can I suppress it if it defined as error in eclipse preferences? another example is "unused local variable". can I set it as error in eclipse preferences but then suppress it for specific class?